# when setting button title giving warning uibutton may not respond to -settitle

Tags: ios, uibutton

When trying to set text to button getting warning UIButton may not respond to -'settitle'.

For below lines of code.

```
[firstButton setTitle:[buttonArray objectAtIndex:0]];

[secondbutton setTitle:[buttonArray objectAtIndex:i+index]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
[firstButton setTitle:[buttonArray objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[secondbutton setTitle:[buttonArray objectAtIndex:i+index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole method signature is – setTitle:forState:

forState: is part of the method name, not an optional parameter.